# Getting Module dynamically

Tags: python, python-2.7, module

I have some modules like this:

```
    Drivers/
        a.py
        b.py
        c.py
```

Now I want to call them on the basis of a variable value.
let us consider driver is the variable from where I will get the variable name.

```
    if driver=='a':
        #then call the driver a and execute.
        a.somefunction()
    if driver=='b':
        #then call the driver b and execute
```

I know the value we get from the driver in if statement is  a string type value and in the if statement we have to call a module.
is there any way to convert it.??

Comment: Why can't you just import them based on your if statements?

Comment: @KobiK Isn't the question (sort of) asking *how* to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your "Drivers/" directory in the searchpath of python, simply import the module and call the function:

```
import importlib
module = importlib.import_module(driver)
module.some_function()
```

Comment: @Nashmaniac You may wish to accept this answer (and get +2 rep).

Answer (score 2):

If the modules are in the same level(exactly your case), just

```
module = __import__(driver)
module.somefunction()
```

`driver` can be `string` such as `'a'`, `'b'`, or `'c'`. If the module does not exist, `ImportError` is raised.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

```
def default_action():
    print('I will do this by default')
    return 42

the_function = default_action 

if driver == 'a':
    from a import somefunction as the_function
if driver == 'b':
    from b import some_other_function as the_function
if driver == 'c':
    from c import some_other_function as the_function

print('Running the code ... ')
result = the_function()
print('Result is: {}'.format(result))
```

You'll have to make sure that the full path to `Drivers/` is in your `PYTHONPATH` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this:

```
import imp
py_mod = imp.load_module(driver, *imp.find_module(driver, ['Drivers']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read here about module search path:
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

this discussion shows how to convert string to command:
http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/198082/converting-string-to-python-code

Basic example for your case would be something like:

assuming a and b are directories in linux in the root

```
import sys
import os

if driver=='a':
    # add /a to the module search path
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(['/', driver]))

    command_string = 'import ' + driver + '.py'

    # converts a string to python command
    exec(command_string)
    #then call the driver a and execute.
    a.somefunction()
if driver=='b':

    sys.path.append(os.path.join(['/', driver]))

    command_string = 'import ' + driver + '.py'

    # converts a string to python command
    exec(command_string)
    #then call the driver b and execute
```